# Output distinct value of JOINS from Stored-procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, join, stored-procedures, distinct

Using an SQL JOIN example from StackOverflow, [What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins)

Would like to know if this is returned from a Store-procedure, how would return distinct value name and phone number from the example below.  Even if I create an XML string, even then I cant select DISTINCT values.  Any help?

```
select name, phone, selling 
from people join property 
on people.pid = property.pid;

+-----------+--------------+----------------------+
| name      | phone        | selling              |
+-----------+--------------+----------------------+
| Mr Brown  | 01225 708225 | Old House Farm       |
| Mr Pullen | 01380 724040 | The Willows          |
| Mr Pullen | 01380 724040 | Tall Trees           |
| Mr Pullen | 01380 724040 | The Melksham Florist |
+-----------+--------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: I'm sorry I can't understand your question well. Are you trying to return distinct values from that Query or what?

Comment: This is distinct values, depends on what you want

Comment: Something like `select name, phone, MAX(selling) selling 
from people join property 
on people.pid = property.pid GROUP BY name, phone`? Just a "random" value from the selling list if there are many for a name/phone#?

Comment: @Tech Bangalore when you post a "how to do in SQL" question its always best to specify your input and expected output. That way even if your wording isn't comprehensible users get a good idea of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Well, combination of name, phone and selling is distinct, so 4 rows will be returned, now in case you need only name and phone to be distinct, then solutions are given below. :)

Answer (score -1):

It's actually a bit unclear

But if you do someting like 

`Select distinct name,phone
from people join property 
on people.pid = property.pid;`

you gonna to have 

 `Mr Brown  | 01225 708225       |
| Mr Pullen | 01380 724040`

Comment: You just copied my answer

Comment: We just post on the same time ;)

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff for formatting the table.  Reiterating my question,

I wanted all the rows matched by the LEFT JOIN, but each column to have distinct values, as, from the table above, Mr Pullen and his phone appears only once since they are the same for the 3 records.

The SP I have has some complex JOINS, I need it to return output with distinct values for each column.  I'm OK if the output is returned as an XML string.   Is this achievable?